# transform flat linear tree representation into memory tree representation

Tags: c#, binary-tree, expression-trees, genetics

I have a string like this:

```
*b+a-aQa
```

and would like to transform it into an hierarchical tree structure like this:

[image]

The tree would consist of nodes like this:

```
public class TreeNode : ITreeNode
{
    public string Expression { get; set; }
    public bool Terminal { get; set; }
        public List<ITreeNode> Children { get; set; }
}

public interface ITreeNode
{
    string Expression { get; set; }
    bool Terminal { get; set; }
    List<ITreeNode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Here expression would be, for example:

*

Terminal indicates if node is terminal node or not (b, a, a, a).

I am trying to come up with an algorithm to create the tree given the string. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

To provide more context this is related to this [paper](https://gene-expression-programming.com/webpapers/GEP.pdf).

PS:

Another example:

```
Q*+-abcd
```

[image]

The meaning of this is as follows (Q = square root):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Henk. Not 100% what you mean. I added another example (see PS). Here left nodes are not terminals.

Comment: But the second example is not an expression tree. Why would Q become the parent of *, and what does that even mean?

Comment: Q is the square root. I'll add the meaning.

Comment: Right. Look up "prefix parser" then.

Comment: But what are the rules? Your first example seems to have a different rule set from the first example.

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled. Not sure what you mean. All this is related to this: https://gene-expression-programming.com/webpapers/GEP.pdf (I edited the post).

Comment: Why does `Q` have only a single child, but `*` have two children? Can a node have more than two children?

Comment: Looks like Reverse Polish Notation which is used in HP calculators.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: @ZoharPeled because the function 'square root' has an arity of 1.

Comment: @jdweng thanks but looking at example: 15 7 1 1 + − ÷ 3 × 2 1 1 + + − => ((15 ÷ (7 − (1 + 1))) × 3) − (2 + (1 + 1)) it does not correspond to the above examples ...

Comment: @jdweng - looks like a mirror image. It isn't Reversed here. RPN is post-fix.

Comment: OK, after a quick look at the paper: "this differs  from  both  the  postfix  and  prefix 
expressions"

Comment: It's kind of a binary heap, but not quite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of like a binary heap, but not quite. You know the structure (0, 1, or 2 children) when you add a Node but you only read the children's content much later.

You can manage this with a Queue instead of a Stack

```
private static Node Parse(TextReader reader)
{            
    var nodes = new Queue<Node>();

    var root = new Node();
    nodes.Enqueue(root);   

    int ch;

    while ((ch = reader.Read()) != -1)
    {
        char token = (char)ch;

        // syntax check 1: the queue should not be empty
        var node = nodes.Dequeue();  
        node.Symbol = token;

        if ("Q".IndexOf(token) >= 0)
        {
            node.Left = new Node();
            nodes.Enqueue(node.Left);
        }
        else if ("+-*".IndexOf(token) >= 0)
        {
            node.Left = new Node();
            nodes.Enqueue(node.Left);
            node.Right = new Node();
            nodes.Enqueue(node.Right);
        }
        // else : 0 children
    }

    // syntax check 2: the queue should now be empty
    return root;         
}
```

and you can call it like

```
var tree = Parse(new StringReader("Q*+-abcd"));
```

Comment: This looks interesting - thanks. Please allow a bit of time to test it.

Comment: Pretty cool. I adapted this to come closer to my use case and it works (not sure how). I tried to use recursions etc.